# Getting 'Unauthorized' Error with Amazon SP-API for Draft App as Private Seller - How to Resolve?

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I am using the Amazon Seller Developer SP-API with a developer account set as a private seller. I've created an app that's currently in draft status. When attempting to retrieve estimated fees using the SP-API, I'm encountering an 'Unauthorized' error with the message 'Access to requested resource is denied.' How to resolve this issue and gain authorized access to the requested resource?

What I've tried:

- I have made the following attempts to resolve the issue:
- Checked my app configuration on the Amazon Seller Developer portal to ensure it's correctly set up.
- Reviewed the SP-API documentation and made sure I'm using the correct endpoints and parameters for estimating fees.
- Verified that the necessary permissions and authorizations are in place for the app within the Amazon Seller Central.

Expectations:

I expected that, I would be able to make SP-API requests to retrieve estimated fees without encountering the 'Unauthorized' error.